# How to create a csv file in c# for downloading and set column type to text

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have an app that already allows the user to download a grid to a csv file utilizing the appropriate headers and content type as follows:

```
thisPage.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
thisPage.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=GridData.csv");
```

When the user opens the csv file in Excel I need some of the columns to automatically format as text.  For reasons beyond this post the download has to be csv and not xsl.

Is there a way to format columns in csv?

Comment: `"application/vnd.ms-excel"` is the content type for the obsolete `xls` format, not CSV. If you want *Excel* to read that file use a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) to create a real `xlsx` file. It's far easier than trying to create a CSV file, quote fields that may contain double quotes or commas, wonder about decimal and date separators.

Comment: There is no format or hinting you can add to a CSV file to change the way Excel handles them by default.

Comment: Creating a real Excel file with EPPlus can be as easy as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(someList)` or `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(someTable)`

Comment: Prepending a value with `'` will cause Excel to treat it as text.

Comment: Which web stack are you using? The code looks like Webforms but it could be MVC, Web API or Razor that uses `Response` instead of the usual `File(...)`

Comment: If you prefix with a ' in a CSV column you will just end up with the ' character in the cell, same as if you prefixed with any other character.

Comment: @AlexK. That is what I assumed, looks like there is no way to fix this legacy bug without an overhaul of the way we are doing things.

Comment: If you output as (e.g.) `="01234"` Excel will show as `01234`

Comment: @TimWilliams My number is 18631889848531002 and it does not display correctly.

Comment: Works for me - did you include the `=` sign ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Actually, that does work. Nice! Create an answer and I'll mark it the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output your field as (e.g.)

```
 ="01234"
```

Excel will show as `01234`.  You must include the `=` sign.

Note this is assuming Excel is the target for the data - some other application will likely choke a bit on that.